# why are file system usage metrics different?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, disk-management

I keep getting warnings my 250GB ssd is running low on space,

from system monitor:
[image: system monitor disk usage]

if I run `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

```bsh
sda                                 232.9G                                
├─sda1                  ext4          731M /boot                          
├─sda2                                  1K                                
└─sda5                  crypto_LUKS 232.2G                                
  └─sda5_crypt          LVM2_member 232.2G                                
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        231.2G /                              
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap          980M [SWAP]                         
sdb                                 931.5G                                
└─sdb1                  ntfs        931.5G /media/dan/Data
```

but looking in disk usage analyzer / only shows 50GB of usage:

[image: disk analyzer 50GB usage]

I try running `sudo du -sh` in `/home` and it too reports 29GB which is what the disk usage analyzer shows also. How can I find what is using the other ~180GB of disk space? is it just being used up because of disk encryption?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the caches Im aware of, nix, go pkg/modules, npm, this freed up some space, but I found that docker volumes were using up 150GB `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)` sorted me out